# require (file.js) gives error.mean version 0.1.2

Tags: node.js, mean.io

i tried normal require for code reuse i get this error

Cannot find module './app/models/test.js'

```
// app/models/test.js

exports={
unit:['l','kg','ton']
}

//app/controllers/enum.js

var val=require('./app/models/test.js')
exports.all = function(req, res){
res.jsonp(val);
}
```

i also tried module.exports but no luck

app folder structure is as per mean.io

Answer (score 0):

needs two points
write like this

```
// app/models/test.js

exports={
    unit:['l','kg','ton']
}

//app/controllers/enum.js

var val=require('../models/test.js') 
exports.all = function(req, res){
    res.jsonp(val);
}
```